# Vaadin 8 Html Imports Javascript

Tags: javascript, vaadin8

I am trying to use Vaadin 8 's "Html Import" feature

i followed instructions here : [What's New In Vaadin 8](https://vaadin.com/framework/whatsnew)

you can check it at 10th feature.

i am also sure that i installed both polymer-cli and bower.As GameCard creator mantioned at his own github.

But when run the application "the cards" are loading but not the way as it should.Mines have no flipping animation and kind a looks bad.

Screenshot :

[image]

Update After Gerald's Solution.

[image: No Flip]

Finally Works with the Right Version of Polymer.
[image: Working Proof]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with the game-card element and the latest version of Polymer. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/vpusher/game-card/issues/4) on GitHub. Try with the version I used when I developed the demo. Find it [here](https://github.com/alejandro-du/vaadin-game-card-demo). Just replace your bower_components directory with the one in my demo.

Comment: Hi Alejandro ,  Unfortunately nothing changed. i even downloaded your project and compile it. Without Gerald's solution i am getting the same erro with the first time i tried.

May be it is about my polymer-cli version. i will try to delete it and re install but i dont know which version should i use.

Do you have any suggestion how do i select polymer-cli version when i am installing ? i just run this command : (npm install -g polymer-cli)

Comment: i tried again but failed with same result.

i realy cant figure out what am i missing. i just run "bower install game-card" and polymer downloaded as well . and it is 2.0 rc version.

Comment: Hi Alejandro ,

i am marking your answer as true. Because it worked !. 

There was 2 problem first my main ui didnt have @JavaScript import webcomponents-lite.

And Second one is browser-caching ! ... i just opened ignogcito tab and viola !!! ...

Comment: by the way i used your bower files. When i delete yours and re-download them. there is a problem. Hope Polymer or game card owner will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

initialize rank and symbol in different order (set rank first):

```
GameCard = function () {
    var element = this.getElement();
    this.setCard = function (symbol, rank) {
        element.set("rank", rank);
        element.set("symbol", symbol);
    };
};
```

Comment: Hi Gerald it did the trick indeed. i am not seeing any errors anymore. But cards have no flipping animation. Do you have any suggestion for that too ?.

Comment: Actually the flipping animation will not work with the polymer element at all. I  tried it with the latest version from github with `polymer serve`.

Comment: so it didnt work for you aswell. i just commented this post's link to tutorial video on youtube. if he response i wil update here also.
For now , i will leave this question unsolved.